# How can I get the path to my photos Internal Storage?

Tags: android

My phone hasn't sdcard.(Nexus 5)

How can I get full path to my photos?

I need this for `ExifInterface(String filename)`

don't work

String imagefile ="/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/image1.jpg";

Comment: The pictures are located in /sdcard/DCIM/

Comment: My phone has not sdcard! I have nexus 5

Comment: It is a virtual sdcard. The folder is only called `sdcard` although the nexus5 has no sdcard.

Comment: thank you very much, I would not have thought of

Comment: FYI, this "virtual sdcard" is actually [eMMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiMediaCard#eMMC) chip in your phone.

Comment: I write                                                                                                      String imagefile ="/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150521_144859.jpg"; but Android Studio use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath  How use this?

Comment: try: 
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath()

Comment: String imagefile =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath()+
     "/Camera/IMG_20150521_144859.jpg";  don't work

Comment: don't work  String imagefile =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath()+
     "/Camera/IMG_20150521_144859.jpg";

Comment: thanks to all!!!!!))))) I add  '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />' and  All Working))) **questions answered**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As questions shouldn't be answered in comments I'll sum it up here:

use the function

```
String pathtoimage= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbs‌​olutePath()+ "/Camera/IMG_20150521_144859.jpg";
```

to get the path to the specific image located in the folder *Camera*.

And don't forget to add the permissions to your *Android-Manifest*  which allow you to read and write to the external storage:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```